# How to make a test case as fail in Junit?

Tags: junit, cucumber-jvm

When i use fail()[Junit] in the script, the scripts stops running and Skipped the next steps.

```
 In TestNG, We can do that using "org.testng.Assert.fail("");" .
```

my requirement is to continue to run the next scenario even if my previous case was failure .

Please help me .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use soft asssertions. Something like this

```
public static void verifyFalse(boolean condition) {
    try {
        assertFalse(condition);
} catch(Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new YourException("your message");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JUnit has the [ErrorCollector rule](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/rules/ErrorCollector.html) for soft assertions.

```java
public class ATest {
  @Rule
  public final ErrorCollector collector = new ErrorCollector();

  @Test
  public void test() {
    //do some stuff
    collector.addError(new Throwable("something went wrong"));
    //do other stuff
  }
}
```